# How to write a custom text reader

Tags: c#, .net

I have a text file containing information in the following format. I want to read the data and perform few operation.What is the best possible way to read this data

```
[Employee Personal]
Name: Wayne Rooney
Age : 34
[End Employee Personal]

[Employee salary]
Salary : 300k/Week
[end Employee salary]

[Employee Personal]
Name: Rashford
Age: 22
[End Employee Personal]

[Employee salary]
Salary : 200k/week
[end Employee salary
```

Comment: Is it a requirement for the file to be formatted like this, with the tags in square brackets? why not just a normal serialisable format like, like json, or xml?

Comment: Yeah, its a legacy code and file format has to be like this

Comment: Just to be clear, it contains `[Employee Personal]` ?

Comment: Yeah.It  indicates start of the block.  [End Employee Personal] indicates  end of that block of data

Comment: Could you show an actual file extract with bogus data (formatted as code)? It's not clear to me how `Name Age` is supposed to work. In addition, are these the *only* fields

Comment: I have updated the question with data, Basically the data file contains collection of employee details block .

Comment: Ao are all the blank lines included? please be specific

Comment: You can ignore the blank lines for now . I want to know how to parse and group this data

Comment: You don't need a custom reader, you just need to write a parser for this. Read the content of the file using the built in `File.ReadAllLines` method into an array of strings and start analyzing the array.

Comment: @Zohar Peled : A parser is a custom reader.

Comment: @jdweng technically, you're correct. What I meant was that the OP can read the file itself into memory using built in classes and only then parse it.

Comment: Why read the entire file into memory?  You do not know the size of the file and it could be huge.  Better to read one line at a time with StreamReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee.ReadFile(FILENAME);
            foreach (Employee employee in Employee.employees)
            {
                Employee.Print(employee);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public static List<Employee> employees { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string salary { get; set; }

        enum State
        {
            PERSONAL,
            SALARY,
            NONE
        }
        public static void ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string line = "";
            State state = State.NONE;
            Employee employee = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("["))
                    {
                        line = line.Replace("[", string.Empty);
                        line = line.Replace("]", string.Empty);

                        if (line.ToUpper().StartsWith("END"))
                        {
                            state = State.NONE;
                            if(line != "End Employee Personal")
                                employee = null;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            switch (line)
                            {
                                case "Employee Personal":
                                    state = State.PERSONAL;
                                    employee = new Employee();
                                    if (employees == null) employees = new List<Employee>();
                                    employees.Add(employee);
                                    break;
                                case "Employee salary":
                                    state = State.SALARY;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(line.Contains(":"))
                        {
                            string[] properties = line.Split(new char[] { ':' }).ToArray();

                            switch (state)
                            {
                                case State.PERSONAL :
                                    switch (properties[0].Trim())
                                    {
                                        case "Name" :
                                            employee.name = properties[1].Trim();
                                            break;
                                        case "Age" :
                                            employee.age = int.Parse(properties[1]);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case State.SALARY :
                                    employee.salary = properties[1].Trim();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static void Print(Employee employee)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name : '{0}', Age : '{1}', Salary : '{2}'", employee.name, employee.age, employee.salary);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This works , I will try something in similar lines .